# Possible to programatically installed 'Untrusted Certificate' or 'P12' file in Keychain Access with 'Always Trust '?

Tags: macos, keychain

I am new to the Keychain Access from mac.
I just have to installed Untrused Certificate or P12 file in keychain access programatically in Mac as 'Trust Always'.

I am using below code :

```
 -(void)addCertificate
  {
    NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
   @"/Users/Desktop/Certificates.p12"];

    CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;
    CFStringRef password = (CFStringRef)@"";
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };

    CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, 
    values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    SecCertificateRef rootCert = 
    SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDataRef) 
    inPKCS12Data);

    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, 
    optionsDictionary, &items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
         NSLog(@" *** Certificate install Success ***");
    } else {
      NSLog(@" *** Certificate install Failure ***");
    }


    OSStatus err = noErr;
    CFTypeRef result;
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
                      rootCert, kSecValueRef,
                      nil];

    err = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict, &result);
    if(err!=noErr) NSLog(@"error while importing");

    if (err==errSecDuplicateItem) NSLog(@"Cert already installed");
    NSLog(@":%i",(int)err);
    assert(err==noErr||err==errSecDuplicateItem);   
   // accept no errors other than duplicate

   err = noErr;
   SecTrustRef trust;

   err = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(rootCert, 
      SecPolicyCreateBasicX509() ,&trust);

   assert(err==noErr);
   err = noErr;

   CFMutableArrayRef newAnchorArray = 
   CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,0,&kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

   CFArrayAppendValue(newAnchorArray,rootCert);

   err = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, newAnchorArray);
   assert(err==noErr);

   SecTrustResultType trustResult;
   err=SecTrustEvaluate(trust,&trustResult);
   assert(err==noErr);
   rootCert=nil;   // Done with the policy object

 }
```

By using this code we are adding certificate only 
Please help me to out from this...

Comment: This poses a very high risk to the system. I think it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is possible to get me the simplest way to do the same.